# scala fast range lookup on 2 columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, range, lookup

I have a spark dataframe that I am broadcasting as Array[Array[String]].
My requirement is to do a range lookup on 2 columns.

Right now I have something like ->

```
val cols = data.filter(_(0).toLong <= ip).filter(_(1).toLong >= ip).take(1) match {
    case Array(t) => t
    case _ => Array()
  }
```

The following data file is stored as Array[Array[String]] (except for the header row that I have shown below only as reference.) and passed to the filter function shown above.

sample data file ->

```
startIPInt | endIPInt  | lat               | lon
676211200  | 676211455 | 37.33053          | -121.83823
16777216   | 16777342  | -34.9210644736842 | 138.598709868421
17081712   | 17081712  | 0                 | 0
```

sample value to search ->

```
ip = 676211325
```

based on the range of the startIPInt and endIPInt values, I want the rest of the mapping rows.

This lookup takes 1-2 sec for each, and I am not even sure the 2nd filter condition is getting executed(in debug mode always it only seems to execute the 1st condition). Can someone suggest me a faster and more reliable lookup here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add sample input DataFrames and expected output please?

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally added sample

Comment: I would love to help you but your question is still unclear to me. It helps if you add all your inputs ( samples) and expected output. Please see this thread 
 for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples

Comment: I think is unclear what are you asking. Can you provide an example of relation between Array[Array[String]] and sample data?

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis